# HTML list still opened after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem:

I have quite complicated HTML multilevel list in which all levels (except the first one) is hidden as default. And after click on a span I display one part of it.

I have really simple jQuery function for it:

```
$("ul.roles li>span").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().find(">ul").slideToggle();
    });
```

But now I want if I click on a link in the third level of the list I want the link is still displayed after clicking on it.

It sends an ajax request that rewrite whole list so jQuery styles isn't there any more and all levels of the html list is again hidden.

---

Code: https://gist.github.com/ed4469e38d8de01ca69f

Comment: You'll have to give us some more code. Specifically, the AJAX/rewriting part.

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to enclose the code :-) ajax.js is a file from nette framework (http://www.nette.org) that proccess the returned JSON.

Comment: Sounds to me like a server side task. on the ajax request - pass the visible nodes and when you render the response, simply don't hide them. Will that work for you?

Comment: You're right. There isn't any client side solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must do it on server side. There propably isn't any client side solution.